# jquery validation simply select

Tags: jquery, validation

how to simply this script. i have few selects and i want to use simple validation everything is ok but i want to make that script shorter.

I dont want to use any libraries to validation

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
 var tmp = $('#select-1').val();
 var tmp1 = $('#select-2').val();
 var tmp2 = $('#select-3').val();
 var error = $('#error-1');
 var error2 = $('#error-2');
 var error3 = $('#error-3');
 if (tmp == '0' || tmp == 'Select') {
  e.preventDefault();
  error.show();
} else {
  error.hide();
}
if (tmp1 == '0' || tmp1 == 'Select') {
  e.preventDefault();
  error2.show();
} else {
  error2.hide();
}
if (tmp2 == '0' || tmp2 == 'Select') {
 e.preventDefault();
 error3.show();
} else {
 error3.hide();
}
});
});
```

here is html code

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <div>

        <label for="select-1">Value 1</label>
        <select id="select-1">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Select 1</option>
            <option value="2">Select 2</option>
            <option value="3">Select 3</option>
        </select>
        <i id="error-1" class="error">Error</i>
    </div>
     <div>

        <label for="select-2">Value 2</label>
        <select id="select-2">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Select 1</option>
            <option value="2">Select 2</option>
            <option value="3">Select 3</option>
        </select>
         <i  id="error-2" class="error">Error</i>
    </div>
     <div>

        <label for="select-3">Value 3</label>
        <select id="select-3">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Select 1</option>
            <option value="2">Select 2</option>
            <option value="3">Select 3</option>
        </select>
         <i  id="error-3" class="error">Error</i>
    </div>
    <div> <button type="submit" id="formsubmission">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to convert the jQuery into vanilla JS?

Comment: belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: i still want to use jquery but i want to make that script shorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generic:

```
$(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function(e) {
    check(1, e);
    check(2, e);
    check(3, e);
  });
});

function check(id, e) {
  var tmp = $('#select-' + id).val();
  var error = $('#error-' + id);
  if (tmp == '0' || tmp == 'Select') {
    e.preventDefault();
    error.show();
  } else {
    error.hide();
  }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mEbbWnosTYBsrMzOrk0P?p=preview)

You can even pass strings to this routine like check('Price',e) to have more readable html-ids (id="select-Price" - id="error-Price").
Also this can be improved by adding another parameter for the value that should trigger the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work

```
$("select").each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).val() == '0' || 'Select') {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next(".error").show();
     } else {
     $(this).next(".error").hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: this doesn't hide the errors when the selection is valid

Comment: @mr.moses edited my answer, but I don't think error should be visible until there is actually an error.

Comment: agreed, but when the invalid field is fixed, the error should be hidden. looks good now :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat yourself (DRY). You're basically doing the same thing 3 times. You can loop your select elements with [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and do your validation in there.

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    $.each("select", function(i,el) {
        var val = $(el).val();  
        if(val == '0' || val == 'Select') {
            $("#error-"+i).show();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $("#error-"+i).hide();
    });
});
```

That takes you from 27 lines down to 10.